# How the URL is formulated in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, url

How is the Drupal path formulated? If we have a Drupal path like channel/1 or like subchannel/2/1, are channel and subchannel taxonomies? How do we look at these data in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the URLs you used as example are not standard URLs that a Drupal site without third-party module handles by default, the answer depends from the modules you installed in your Drupal site.
For example, there could be a module that handles RSS feeds; the module could return the content of a RSS feed for URLs such as example.com/channel/1 and the partial content of a RSS feed with URLs similar to example.com/subchannel/2/1.

Actually you could have created a path alias that points example.com/channel/1 to example.com/taxonomy/term/1, but for Drupal there isn't an automatic association between example.com/channel/1 and example.com/taxonomy/term/1, or any taxonomy term URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer.

Many parts of Drupal and its modules affect URLs. For example, you can use the Pathauto module to assign an arbitrary path to a particular node. If you use Views, you can specify a path to display it, and even use extra path elements as arguments.

Unfortunately, you can't just look at the database to see how the paths work.